# Ionic2 + Firebase :: build dev failed

Tags: firebase, ionic2

I've been having this issue for the last couple of days and was able to narrow down the culprit just today:

Starting with a brand new project, and adding `firebase` to it:

```
ionic start -a "MyApp" -i com.package.xyz MyApp tabs --v2
npm install --save firebase
```

At this point, `ionic serve` works correctly. But if I import `firebase` in any file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
```

Now running `ionic serve --debug` throws the following errors:

```
******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,      
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:     

 Install ios-sim to deploy iOS applications.`npm install -g ios-sim` (may require sudo)
 Install ios-deploy to deploy iOS applications to devices.  `npm install -g ios-deploy` (may require sudo)

******************************************************

> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve /Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp
> ionic-app-scripts serve "--debug"

[13:27:37]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.45 
[ DEBUG! ]  An BuildUpdateStarted event occurred  MEM: 116.7MB 
[ DEBUG! ]  An BuildUpdateCompleted event occurred  MEM: 116.7MB 
[ DEBUG! ]  An FileChange event occurred  MEM: 116.9MB 
[ DEBUG! ]  An ReloadApp event occurred  MEM: 116.9MB 
[13:27:38]  watch started ... MEM: 117.2MB 
[13:27:38]  build dev started ... MEM: 117.2MB 
[13:27:38]  clean started ... MEM: 117.2MB 
[ DEBUG! ]  clean /Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/www/build  MEM: 117.2MB 
[13:27:38]  clean finished in 6 ms MEM: 117.4MB 
[13:27:38]  copy started ... MEM: 117.4MB 
[13:27:38]  transpile started ... MEM: 117.5MB 
[13:27:42]  build dev failed: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined  MEM: 253.7MB
[ DEBUG! ]  TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined at loadDiagnostic 
            (/Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/logger/logger-typescript.js:47:27)
            at 
            /Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/logger/logger-typescript.js:12:16
            at Array.map (native) at Object.runTypeScriptDiagnostics 
            (/Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/logger/logger-typescript.js:11:26)
            at /Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:92:47 at 
            transpileWorker 
            (/Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:62:12) at 
            Object.transpile 
            (/Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:26:12) at 
            buildDev 
            (/Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:84:24) at 
            buildWorker 
            (/Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:35:12) at 
            Object.build 
            (/Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:19:12)  
            MEM: 253.7MB 
[ DEBUG! ]  listening on 8100  MEM: 253.9MB 
[ DEBUG! ]  watcher ready: 
            /Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/src/assets/,/Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/src/index.html,/Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/src/manifest.json,/Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/src/service-worker.js,node_modules/ionic-angular/polyfills/polyfills.js,node_modules/ionicons/dist/fonts/
             MEM: 253.8MB 
[13:27:42]  copy finished in 3.69 s MEM: 253.8MB 
[ DEBUG! ]  watcher ready: 
            /Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Users/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/src/**/*.(ts|html|scss)
             MEM: 253.8MB 
[13:27:42]  watch ready in 3.70 s MEM: 253.8MB 
[13:27:42]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/
```

If I remove the import, `ionic serve` works correctly again.

Here is the output of `ionic info`:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.45
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.7.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

How can I correct this error?

Asim

---

**EDIT**

I've traced the error down to `node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts` in the last section which says:

```
declare module 'firebase' {
  export = firebase;
}
```

For this, the compiler complains: `Duplicate identifier 'export='.`

If I remove this section, or the `export = firebase;` line, the error goes away and `ionic serve` works fine, but I lose access to the `firebase` object.

Even more oddly, if I start with a blank project with only `firebase` added, and run `ionic serve`, things work fine. Next, I import `firebase` in one of my source files and everything works fine still. Until I terminate `ionic serve` and restart it. At that point, I get the same error as the one listed near the top of the post.

I've even updated my `node`, `ionic`, `cordova` and `ionic-app-scripts`. `ionic info` now shows:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.46
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Still the same issue though. I desperately need help to resolve this issue.. =/

---

**EDIT**

For more info:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.46",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "firebase": "^3.6.2",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.45",
    "typescript": "2.0.6"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

**npm versions**

```
npm@3.10.8
cordova@6.4.0
ionic@2.1.14
typescript@2.0.10
firebase@3.6.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the Same Problem look here:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/build-dev-failed-cannot-read-property-indexof-of-undefined/71506

Comment: Hey! I managed to solve the issue.. by REINSTALLING my OS.. =/ I was getting countless headaches due to this issue and as a last resort I refreshed my mac.. Having reinstalled nodejs and every dependency (ionic, cordova, libs, etc), the issue went away.. So im guessing something got corrupted in my previous installations that caused problems.. Perhaps if I had removed all nodejs binaries and libraries and reinstalled from scratch, it mightve worked too..